# Simplifying a trigonometric function with arctan

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

Why is this trigonometric expression with $\arctan$ not simplified ?

```
ArcTan[Tan[γ[t] - θ[t]]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note

```
Plot[{ArcTan[Tan[a]], a}, {a, -Pi, Pi},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Consequently, some assumptions are needed to get the simplification

```
Assuming[{-Pi/2 < γ[t] - θ[t] < Pi/2}, 
 Simplify[ArcTan[Tan[γ[t] - θ[t]]]]]

(*  γ[t] - θ[t]  *)
```

Or use [PowerExpand](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand.html)

```
ArcTan[Tan[γ[t] - θ[t]]] // PowerExpand

(*  γ[t] - θ[t]  *)
```