# Generating a sawtooth wave

Tags: functions, fourier-analysis

I would like to build this piecewise function

[image: piecewise function]

Please help me to find the appropriated code.

P.S: In a second step, I would like to obtain the Fourier series of this function.

Comment: Look up `SawtoothWave[]`. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109775) as well.

Comment: I tried this f[x_] = SawtoothWave[{-1, 1}, x] but it is not yet the result i want. Moreover, does Mathematica know how to use this function to calcultate the Fourier series ?

Answer (score 4):

```
f[x_] := SawtoothWave[{-1, 1}, (x + 1)/2]
Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image: plot]

and perhaps this for the 1st 20 terms.

```
g[x_] = FourierSinSeries[f[x], x, 20];
Plot[g[x], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update

Or perhaps you are looking for this.

```
 a[n_] = FourierSinCoefficient[f[x], x, n]
```

> ```
> -((2 ((-1)^n (-4 + π) + 2 Cos[n] + 2 Cos[3 n]))/(n π))
> ```

```
 h[x_] = Sum[a[n] Sin[n x], {n, 20}];
 Plot[h[x], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: thank you for your help, is there a function which gives directly all the Fourier Series that is to say with the an (terms related to the cosinus) and bn (terms related to the sinus)

Comment: @Bendesarts. Mathematica has around 20 functions for working with Fourier series. Pleas consult the documentation.

Comment: of course, thank you but, i didn't see this one and normally it should be the most direct function

Comment: @Bendesarts. I not sure I understand what you think is "the most direct function", but I made an update based on a guess. To my thinking, `h` is no more direct than `g`.